# Android listview from linkedHashMap

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to figure out how to create a listview (preferably with an inner_view so I can display certain information from each map entry in the cells). Does anyone know of some good tutorials out there? I have been really struggling to find complete examples of creating a listview with a map.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is extend the `BaseAdapter` class to make your own custom adapter for handling the `LinkedHashMap`.  Then, you can override the methods relevant to sending data for the `ListView` to display, as well as adding or removing from the internal `LinkedHashMap`.

edit: Check out examples for making a custom ArrayAdapter since it is similar to convert that to handling your HashMap implementation.

Comment: How would that look? Sorry, I've done extensive java stuff, but am fairly new to android. So i have `public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

Comment: Would it just make more sense to convert the map to a list?

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey It depends what you are trying to do.  A List usually works better with a ListView because it is meant to display items sequentially, whereas a HashMap has no intrinsic ordering.  You could convert it on the fly each time to a List if you want to keep using a HashMap though.